# Finding the object count within an object

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a method that is called like this

```
var data = new List<string>{"foo", value};
var event = MakeEvents("module", new object[]{data, "Notes:", notes, "Date:", DateTime.Now);
```

within MakeEvents, I break up the objectData array with a foreach look

```
foreach (var obj in objectData)
        {
            if (obj.ToString().Contains("List"))
                ev.data = SerialiseData((List<string>)obj);
            if (obj.GetType().ToString().Contains("System.DateTime"))
                ev.date = (DateTime)obj;
            if (obj.GetType().ToString().Contains("Boolean"))
                ev.is_deleted = (bool)obj;
            if (obj.GetType().ToString().Contains("Guid"))
                ev.parent_object_id = ((Guid)obj).ToString();
            if (obj.GetType().ToString() == "System.String")
            {
                var t = ((string)obj).Split(':').ToList();
                if (t.Count == 1)
                    ev.notes = (string)obj;
                else
                {
                    switch (t[0])
                    {
                        case "Notes":
                            ev.notes = t[1];
                            break;
                        case "Updated":
                            ev.updated_by = t[1];
                            break;
                        case "Parent":
                            ev.parent_object_id = t[1];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The issue I'm having is that the first parameter in the object is List, but it is not being recognised as such, but does give me a count of the number of objects within data.

I've tried using Enumerable.Count(obj) to get the number objects within data, but I'm given an error that I'm mixing Enumerable with IEnumerable (The type arguments for method System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable) cannot be inferred from the usage).

Is there a simple way of obtaining the count from obj?

Comment: Should the first if statement be if (obj.ToString().Contains("List")) or if (obj.GetType().ToString().Contains("List"))?

Comment: You should use `if obj is bool` instead of trying to match the name of the type.

Comment: Your type checking is *really* fragile. Use proper type checking

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is trying to match the result of calling `ToString` on the list. You should use `is` instead:

```
if (obj is List<string>) { ... }
```

and likewise for all your other dynamic type checks.

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for all the other comments too. Much appreciated.

Comment: For this though, data is not being recognised as being List<string> but when viewed in the debugger I'm seeing objData[2], then in the loop obj[3] with obj[0] being the list - but not showing as a list, but an array.